# is there a validation or a way to check and to allow only one value for the two entities?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a validation that checks that if there is already a value for that entity or not. If there is then it doesnt let the user save another value without destroying the previous one.

I can display a message that the user has to destroy the previous value before creating a new one. That is not the issue.

The question is **is there a validation or a way to check and to allow only one value for the two entities**?

I have two fields length and breadth and I only wish to have one value for length and one for breadth.

Thank you soo much for reading the question. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: custom validation is fine but I'd definitely add db constraints.

Comment: I think you almost always want both.  The db constraints being the last line of defense for a bad state in the database. Plus, as the other have shown, there are simple database-level mechanisms for establishing uniqueness.  The rails validations will be able to produce a much better error message.  One thing to note, validates_uniqueness in rails is going to be much slower than index-level contraints, for instance.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem from a slightly higher level?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`validates_uniqueness_of`](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000086) builtin validation, with the `:scope` option:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :length, :scope => :breadth
```

Comment: This statement works but it only checks the uniqueness of the value. So it works fine if I try to add the same value for length but this doesnt work in case there is any new value added. So if there is a length already present as "10" and breadth as say "x" then it wont stop me from adding another length as "20". There may have been some confusion, actually I want there to be only one value for length and one value for breadth present in the system at any given time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you need provide uniqueness combination of 2 fields.

Then on the example of `users` table

**model.rb**

```
validates :field1, uniqueness: { :scope => :field2}
```

**console**

```
rails generate migration add_index_for_field1_and_field2_to_users
```

**edit migration**

```
class AddIndexFoField1AndField2ToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :users, [:field1, :field2], unique: true
  end
end
```

run migration

```
rake db:migrate
```

Voila!

**UPDATE**

How to check if you made it correct.

**console**

```
Model.create!(field1:"foo",field2:"bar") # true
Model.create!(field1:"foo",field2:"bar") # ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Field1 has already been taken
```

**sql database**:

```
insert into table(field1, field2) values ("foo","bar") # true
insert into table(field1, field2) values ("foo","bar") # ERROR: diplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_table_on_field1_and_field2"
```

Comment: Sorry this also did not stop from another value for length and breadth to get stored in the database. I wish to have only one value for length and only one for breadth. Thank you

Comment: I ran this step by step in my application.

Comment: And..you can add two rows in your table with same (field1, field2) values?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am still new to rails. I followed the steps as you have mentioned but they dont seem to work for me. I have edited the question. Thank you

Comment: Try to check yourself according my UPDATE. Let me know where it will go wrong.

Comment: the complete code is here: https://github.com/abhishekdagarit/mars-rover.git   I am putting it up as I still have this problem. Thank you..

Comment: You didn't answer my previous question.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers will ensure that the combination of :field1 and :field2 values are unique. I am having difficulty understanding the question, but I think abhishek is actually looking for a simpler answer.

I believe he wants to ensure that there is only one value for length and one value for breadth.

Are length and breadth associations? or attributes?  Either case, you probably don't need to call `destroy` to replace them.  Just change the values, either the attribute or within the association, and save.

Can you clarify?

---

Ok, so based on your Grid model, you will never have more than one value for these fields.
You could [mark the record as readonly](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-readonly-21) after the initial successful validation.  Then anytime the user attempts to update the value, there will be a validation error.  You will need to write some simple logic to override the readonly flag to suite your needs.

Now, if you always want to trigger a validation error if there is an existing value, then you can do something like this:

```
validate :error_if_length_exists, :if 'length.present?'
validate :error_if_breadth_exists, :if 'breadth.present?'

def error_if_length_exists
  errors.add(:length, "already exists, are you sure you want to update?")
end

def error_if_breadth_exists
  errors.add(:breadth, "already exists, are you sure you want to update?")
end
```

---

I think you want to use `unless`:

```
def is_it_square
  unless (length == breadth)
     errors.add(:length, "Latest research and our experience shows that a rectangular region is more effective for this kind of mission.")
  end  
end
```

You can also scope the validations like so:
`validates :length, :breadth, :presence_of => true, :on => :create` to only apply the `presence_of` check when you are first creating the record.

It seems like you might want to have different validations for :create vs :update.

---

I think I am definitely misunderstanding the problem you are trying to solve.  A couple suggestions.

1. I do not think you should ask the user to enter both values, if you are going to simply add an error when they are not the same.  A solution for usability would be to add your error text near the input ('we have found that a square is the optimal shape...'), have the user enter one attribute (you really don't need both length and breadth if they always represent the same value), and change your calcs to square that value, rather than multiplying length * breadth.
2. If you need both length/breadth, can you explain the problem a little more clearly.  Suppose you have a form or an interface that records attributes :length and :breadth for a given model.  You do not have an instance of the model yet.  This is the first time the user interacts with your system.  The inputs are sent as part of a request to your controller and you create an object with valid :length and :breadth values.  Subsequently, the user wants to change the :length and :breadth.  Do you want to create a new instance of the model that contains :length/:breadth, or do you want to update the :length/:breadth attributes of the existing model instance?

Comment: Ok, just saw you added more details.

Comment: Matt Dressel, This really seemed like it would work and I was very excited to try it out but it doesnt work. I tried the code but it still allows multiple values to get stored. Thank you

Comment: I need the shape to be rectangular and not square. In the error as well I have mentioned: **rectangular region is more effective for this kind of mission** And in the code I earlier had `if` `length == breadth` then give error and not `unless`. But for this thing to work I am willing to change that if it is needed. No issues.

Comment: Okie this is a valid and a very important point you mentioned here. If the person is using the application for the first time there should be an existing value for length and breadth. but there isn't. To clarify I am putting the link to the github repo for all the code here: https://github.com/abhishekdagarit/mars-rover.git